# Copy Data from multiple text files into an existing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, import, user-input

I am looking to allow the user to select upto 5 text files at a time and copy paste the data into an existing sheet within excel. Each text file is to be added after the previous file. Meaning if the first file has been imported from Column A1 to A200, then second file must be pasted from row A201 and so forth and so on. I am using the following code which allows the user to select one file only. i am looking to just copy paste the data from these text files into the excel without any formatting. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub importdata()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select file extracted", FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rawdata").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make use of the `MultiSelect` argument for your `GetOpenFilename` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit ' It is a good practice to use this to force the compiler to ask for
                ' Var declaration before use it

Sub importdata()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim RngCopy As Range  ' Var to store the range you want to copy
    Dim RngPaste As Range ' Var to store the rante you want paste the txt file data
    Dim A As Worksheet    ' ActiveSheet of the open book stored in "OpenBook" var
    Dim B As Worksheet: Set B = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rawdata") '... Well RawData...
    Dim r
    Dim p
    Dim i
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                        Title:="Select file extracted", _
                        FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*", _
                        MultiSelect:=True)
    'As mention Ron Rosenfeld, you need to use Multiselect

    'Since you want several files, you need a LOOP, a For Loop!
    For Each i In FileToOpen ' no matter if is 1 or many files you take, will work
        If FileToOpen = "False" Then Exit Sub 'But if you take no files will exit with no error
    'If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen) 'the macro open the file
        Set A = OpenBook.ActiveSheet 'Store the active sheet inside A
        r = A.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'Here look for the last cell, this is like
                                                               ' press the CTRL+END keys in the keyboard
                                                               'I asume your data in only en column A
                                                               'goto to the last cell and take the number of the row
        Set RngCopy = A.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1)) 'Take the whole range, and I asume you want to take
                                                        'From A1 to the last row, A1000 ej.
        'OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy
        B.Activate 'Go to rawdata!
        p = B.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Here! From the very last cell.
                                                  'Notice: if you have Excel 97 and before, you need to change to
                                                  '65000, if not, 1000000 will work.
                                                  'From the A1000000 to the top, tell the row + 1
                                                  'Mean... one row bellow the last row in your data.

        Set RngPaste = B.Range(Cells(p, 1), Cells(p + r, 1)) 'Look Here!
                                                             'The last cell (last row + 1 = p) of your data in rawData plus
                                                             'The data you want to insert bellow that data.
                                                             'p + the count of the rows in the new data (r)
                                                             'p + r
                                                             'all this just in column A
        RngPaste.Value = RngCopy.Value
        'We don't use COPY, only if is necesary!
        'We transfer data from here to there!
        'Now we can tell B = A
        'B.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False 'Good Boy!!!

        'it is good practice to clean your vars/objects
        Set OpenBook = Nothing
        Set A = Nothing
        Set B = Nothing
        Set RngCopy = Nothing
        Set RngPaste = Nothing
     'End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Tell me if is right, to edit and fix anything.

Comment: Thank you so much Elbert! i had to make small tweaks based on my file names and such. but other than that it works. thank you so much! @Elbert